# TypeError when selecting an element of an array

Tags: python, arrays

So i'm trying to make it so it will only show ['red'] or ['blue'] and not ['red','9'] or ['blue','9'], however it either shows the previous or 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'
does anyone know how to correctly show this?

```
import random
deck=[['red','9'],['blue','9']]
random.shuffle(deck)
p1=[]
p1.append(deck[0])
print(p1[0][0])
```

Comment: `print(p1[0,[0]])` do you mean `print(p1[0][0])` instead?

Comment: @jean questioner want output `['blue']` rather not `blue`. please convert it to list.

Comment: That is a list, not an array.why did you expect `p1[0,[0]]` to work at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry I'm new to python and this is my first time with lists and arrays and I meant p1[0][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a list of list, to access to an element use

```py
deck[0][0]
```

`l = p1[0]` so `l` is `['red','9']`

and you want `l[0]` in a list so your output will be :

```py
p1 = [deck[0][0]]
```

Comment: Questioner want output `['blue']` rather not `blue`. please convert it to list.

Comment: oh yes I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Lets create new list with all 0 index of sub list using `[_[0] for _ in deck]` then we shuffle that `deck` and access 0th index item in our format `[str]`

```
import random

deck=[['red','9'],['blue','9']]
deck = [_[0] for _ in deck]
random.shuffle(deck) 
print([f'{deck[0]}'])
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].